# fetch - setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, setstate

На 21 строчке, если просто посмотреть на user,
то всё хорошо, но если я хочу посмотреть на user.cell, выдает вот это

[image: console.log(user)]

[image: console.log(user.cell)]

Comment: выводи так `console.log(user && user.cell)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Картина 1:

- При первом рендере юзера не было и в лог попал незаметный undefined.
- При втором рендере юзер подгрузился и видно много данных

Картина 2:

- При первом рендере юзера не было и попытка взять cell у undefined, которая упала
- Второго рендера уже видимо не было

Пишите `(user && user.cell)`.

Можете еще посмотреть про "Error Boundaries".